# WebJobs & Service Bus Triggered Functions - Performance considerations

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I've a WebJobs that contains almost 10 different functions, each triggered by a ServiceBusTrigger, ovbiously from different Service Bus queues.

I'd like to have a high throughput and so I configured:

- PrefetchCount to 200
- MaxConcurrentCalls to 100

on the WebJob Main method like this:

```
var host = new JobHost(config);
config.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusConfiguration()
{
    PrefetchCount = 200,
    MessageOptions = new OnMessageOptions() { MaxConcurrentCalls = 100 },
});
```

I think that this PrefetchCount and ConcurrentCalls are shared between all the functions contained in this WebJob. Is this a correct assumption?

If yes, in order to have a MaxConcurrentCalls of 100 on a single function, is take out each function to a different dedicated WebJob the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

Those settings are host wide, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/1de090007faf07fe6d22c75d9cac5851609502ad/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/MessagingProvider.cs#L104) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/1de090007faf07fe6d22c75d9cac5851609502ad/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Listeners/ServiceBusListener.cs#L38). I'm not 100% sure but you may be able to create your own MessageReceiver, this [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/v2.x/src) has some samples. If it's only one function though, I would just split it off to its own WebJob host.